# Is it possible to undo `git checkout --theirs/ours`?

Tags: git

I am in the middle of a merge and I just did `git checkout --theirs my_file` while I wanted to `git checkout --ours my_file`.

Is there a way to reverse it?

Comment: Just checkout the correct version?

Comment: @matt well thanks... `git checkout <version> -- my_file` did the trick.

Comment: If the problem was trivially solved delete the question?

Comment: well wouldn't have been without you pointing that out... Maybe I should let it stay there, if it still have more downvotes than upvotes at the end of the day I'll delete.

Comment: This naming is really nonsense, it caused me to lose a lot of changes during a merge!

Comment: @Mahmoud_Mehri hi, sorry that this got you into git troubles. Any way you see we could clarify the naming? I am not sure I understand _how_ you go confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: just `git checkout --ours my_file`

---

As proposed by @matt in comments, you can checkout a desired specific version with `git checkout <version> -- my_file`.

And the most simple way to do it is in fact to type the second command `git checkout --ours my_file` since `--ours` and `--theirs` are references to the base branch and merged branch. so it is basically like @matt's solution with a simpler reference.